# Angular 4 component with multiple classes

Tags: angular

I have an app with a component that have few functions inside and I want to make it more readable - what will be the right way / best practice:

Having a service and inject in the construction? or a separate class (let's say MyClass.class.ts) with the functions? and then import the class and create a new object in the component:

```
let myObj = new MyClass();
```

Which takes me for the next question:

2. Either If I use the first option of creating a service, or the second option of creating a separate class - can I bind the properties from the service / class to the component view?

Means, let's say the service looks something like this:

```
export class MyService {
    a: string = 'Hello world'; 
    b: number;

    c(): number {
      this.b += 1;
      return b;
   }

}
```

and the component:

```
export class myComponent {
     constructor(myService: myService){}

     ngOnInit {
       this.myService.c();
 }
```

and then in the HTML template to do something like this:

```
<p>{{a}}</p>
<p>{{b}}</p>
```

So it will output the value of a and b.

The question is if by injecting the service to component, the properties became available to bind in the HTML template?

And in case of a class, something like:

```
export class MyClass {
     a: string = 'Hello world'; 
     b: number;

    c(): number {
      this.b += 1;
      return b;
   }
}



import { MyClass } from './
export class myComponent {

    constructor(){}
    let myClass = new MyClass();

    ngOnInit {
      this.c();
    }  

}
```

This just a general description of my situation. The thing is that I have few good hundreds lines of code and all the functions should be under one component, so I was thinking should I create a new class or a service, but then if I can bind the properties from the class / service to the html template of the component.

It's mean, if by injecting service / creating new object of the class, the properties become available to bind in the component's html template?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should not initiate classes inside other classes because this is how you get a coupled application.

Angular provides you **Dependency Injection** to make your life easier. Use it.

Secondly, if you have a service where you have `a`, `b` and `c`, you should first decide which of them you want to expose.

if `c` is returning a transformed `b`, then `b` should be private for this specific service and should not be exposed.

If all you are trying to do is **intentionally** expose all of your service properties and methods so you can **bind** them in your component, then you need to make sure you are referring to your service name first like this:

service:

```
export class MyService {
        a: string = 'Hello world'; 
        b: number = 1;

        c(): number {
          this.b += 1;
          return this.b;
    }
}
```

component.ts:

```
export class myComponent {
    constructor(public myService: MyService){}
}
```

component.html:

```
<p>{{myService.a}}</p>
<p>{{myService.b}}</p>
<p>{{myService.c()}}</p>
```

Comment: Thanks. a, b, c was just for the example. In my app I need to expose some properties in order to bind in the component. So I guess the answer for the first question is to use service rather than just class because of the dependency injection. About referring to the service name when binding I was not aware. Thanks.

Comment: Would it be better practice to use observable and subscribe to the service properties that I want to bind rather then refer them? Also, what's the reason I need to refer them? They not available automatically once I inject them in the component's constructor?

Answer (score 0):

From angular.io:

> Having multiple classes in the same file can be confusing. We
> generally recommend that you define components and services in
> separate files.
>
> If you do combine a component and service in the same file, it is
> important to define the service first, and then the component. If you
> define the component before the service, you get a run-time null
> reference error.
>
> It is possible to define the component first with the help of the
> forwardRef() method as explained in this blog post
> (http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/09/03/forward-references-in-angular-2.html).
>
> You can also use forward references to break circular dependencies.
> See an example in the DI Cookbook
> (https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action#forwardref).

So in short, it is recommended to have separate files for components and services, but you can still have them in one file with some cautions.